# Grid lines in d3 js don't match the axes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to make a multi-line chart with d3.js in react. The plot looks fine and comes up well, but the gridlines are not aligned sometimes. It is very random, and sometimes some graphs have aligned gridlines, some don't.
This is how some of them look:

[image: Example Chart 1]

[image: Example Chart 2]

I have this code for my gridlines:

```
        svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'grid')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
            .call(
                d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                    .tickSize(-height)
                    .tickFormat(() => ""),
            );
        svg
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'grid')
            .call(
                d3.axisLeft(yScale)
                    .tickSize(-width)
                    .tickFormat(() => ""),
            );
```

I followed this example: https://betterprogramming.pub/react-d3-plotting-a-line-chart-with-tooltips-ed41a4c31f4f

Any help on how I can align those lines perfectly would be appreciated.

Comment: They grid is aligned with the axis ticks - it looks aligned to me - are you speaking of when a tick is close to the axis and results in two lines close to each other? Easiest option would be remove the axis line in these cases I suppose, but that might not be satisfactory in all use cases. Modifying the ticks to align with the edges of the plot area requires either messier ticks, eg: 2:59:14.441, modifying the extent of data values, or removing ticks (resulting in an irregular grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider [`nice`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/README.md#continuous_nice)ing your y-scale so that minima and maxima of your data sets are rounded down/ up such that the ticks are equally spaced.

In your tutorial this bit of code:

```
const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, yMaxValue]);
```

Can become:

```
const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, yMaxValue])
    .nice(); // <--------------------------- here
```

Here's a basic example of using `nice` on an x-scale where the first example is 'not nice' and the second is 'nice'.

```js
// note gaps of 10 between data points
// apart from first and last where gap is different
const data = [3, 4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 47];

// svg
const margin = 20;
const width = 360;
const height = 140;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
  .attr("height", height + margin + margin);
  
// scale without 'nice'
const xScale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(d3.extent(data));

// scale with nice
const xScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .nice();
  
// plot axes with both scales for comparison
// not 'nice'
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin},${margin})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale1));

// 'nice'
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin},${margin + 50})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```